# How to pass environment variable to process started as mvn jetty:run?

Tags: maven, maven-jetty-plugin

The process started by maven jetty plugin seems ignoring any environment variables I specify.
So far I've tried adding variable through command line like:

```
set myvariable=1
```

Also I've tried adding something like "-Dmyvariable=1" to MAVEN_OPTS variable.

Nothing helps.
Just to be clear, I need to pass variable not to maven but to the resulting process, i.e. directly to jetty server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify a [systemProperties](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin#MavenJettyPlugin-sysprops) section in the plugin's configuration:

```
<project>
  ...
  <plugins>
    ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
         ...
         <systemProperties>
            <systemProperty>
              <name>myvariable</name>
              <value>1</value>
            </systemProperty>
            ...
         </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>
</project>
```